# Scattered people with heights

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

There is a line of scattered people and we need to restore the order.

We know:

- How tall each of them are
- The number of people who were in front of them who are taller.

This information is contained in a set

```
Person {
    int height;
    int tallerAheadCount;
}
```

I’ve tried sorting it multiple ways, but no luck.

What I managed to figure out is that the shortest person’s `tallerAheadCount` should match the original index, but this doesn't work in a for loop with sorted heights.

Sorting by `tallerAheadCount`, and then by `height` gives us a relatively close answer, but the higher the `tallerAheadCount` the more incorrect it seems to get. I can’t figure out a rule to merge the shorter people to lower `tallerAheadCount` sorted lines.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Why is this tagged as python?

Comment: Perhaps your question would be clearer if you explained what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore the order" ?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, the problem is that people were standing in a line and they scattered due to an emergency. Original order is unknown, that’s the question really to reassign the indexes. Tagged for python as the set is formatted as py, but yes the question is question is more broad, i removed it.

Comment: Why do you say that something which includes things like `int height;` is formulated as python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little to go on, but I suppose something like this could be what you're after.

This is probably not the most efficient implementation, and not sure it covers all cases (e.g. duplicates), but it's a start:

```py
import random

# dummy data [(height, taller_ahead_count), ...]
original_line = [
    (10, 0), (12, 0), (3, 2), (8, 2), (9, 2), (5, 4), (1, 6), (4, 5), (2, 7)]

# "scatter" the people
scattered_line = original_line.copy()
random.shuffle(scattered_line)

# restore the original line order based on the taller_ahead_count
descending_height = sorted(scattered_line, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
restored_line = []
for height, taller_ahead_count in descending_height:
    taller_count = 0
    j = 0
    while taller_count < taller_ahead_count and j < len(restored_line):
        if restored_line[j] > height:
            taller_count += 1
        j += 1
    restored_line.insert(j, height)

# verify result
assert [height for height, __ in original_line] == restored_line
```

The basic idea is as follows:

We iterate over people in order of descending height, i.e. from tallest to shortest. That way, at each iteration, we are certain that all people taller than the current person are already in the `restored line`. We can then count the number of taller people to find the spot where the current person should be inserted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @djvg it’s very much appreciated. No this is not my homework, i’m looking into sorting algorithms myself and found this problem with no solution, so i tried solving it, but ultimately failed, that’s why i asked for help.